# JS Check property exists for number values

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have used like below example to check property exists on an object.

```
const payload ={payment:0}

if(payload && payload.payment){
  console.log(payload.payment)
}else{
  console.log('Issue')
}
```

But it fails with 0 (Zero) value.

This question is about an object which has integer key and when the key value is zero most of the other answers don't work.

Comment: Have you tried it? `'payload' in payment` does work.

Comment: @FlorianWeimer I found `has` in `lodash` also do this.

Answer (score 3):

To see if the property `payment` exists in the object `payload` you can write

```
'payment' in payload
```

or if you want to know if the property is directly defined in the object (as opposed to being inherited through the prototype), say

```
payload.hasOwnProperty('payment')
```

The expression `payload.payment`, when the value is 0, will produce `false` when used as a boolean. This is because the following values will always act like `false`:

- `0`
- `false`
- `NaN`
- `undefined`
- `null`
- empty strings

The technical term for these values, that act as `false`, is "falsy." So because 0 is falsy, whenever you write `!payload.payment`, this value is actually `true` for `0` and `false` for everything else. Check for the missing property using one of the two techniques above (`in` or `hasOwnProperty`).

Comment: I found `has` in `lodash` also do this.